Create a PAGE using wordpress API using the PAGE template and change specific content
im not sure if i had to create a custom endpoint for this but i do (still dont know what to write inside the function), basically in Pages Section, I made one Page and turn it into a Template. I want to use that template to create a new page via the wordpress API, that page is created from elementor, and basically i want to change the heading for example of a text block from elementor as a starter. help

Creating a page via PHP or via the REST API is easy enough to do but your Elementor requirement means that a good chunk of your question can't be asked here and should be asked in an Elementor community, questions about 3rd party plugins and products are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope. What you want to do requires Elementor specialist knowledge of how Elementor works, how it stores data, and how to adjust it

thats fair, while we are at it, does passing html code in content works? will that render correctly with lets say css class?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
